# Pics disappear in mobile browser when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a website at jacobtarr.github.io where I post a portfolio of some of my work at jacobtarr.github.io/work. As you can see, I have two slides: one where post some screenshots of an individual project and the other where I post preview thumbnails for other projects. When one clicks on a thumbnail image, the DOM is emptied and is filled with pertinent info about that specific project to which it is associated to. The problem I'm having, which only happens on mobile device browser apparently, is the screenshots for the project in the upper slide don't appear when someone clicks on a thumnbnail image in the lower slide. All of the other stuff appears, but not the screenshot.

This is demonstrated from the photos I took: The first one is a screenshot I took from the Chrome when the browser shrinks to the appropriate screen size. The project screenshots appear fine in this when a user clicks on a thumbnail image in the lower slide. The second one is a screenshot I took from an iOS simulator mimicking the exact same behavior.

What is it I'm doing in my code that does this? If it's any help, I'm using the slick slider plugin. If anyone can help me out here, I would greatly appreciate it. I've posted the necessary functions in the JS below as well.

**Chrome (browser width < 400px)**

[image]

**iOS Simulator - iPhone retina 4-inch (portrait)**

[image]

**app.js**

```
    /* Set Slick slider settings
=============================== */
slickSliderConfig = function() {

var projectGalleryArrowPrev = '<a><img class="project-gallery__arrow--prev" src="../img/work/arrow-left-btn.svg"></a>'
var projectGalleryArrowNext = '<a><img class="project-gallery__arrow--next" src="../img/work/arrow-right-btn.svg"></a>'

$('.project-gallery').slick({
    speed: 300,
    slide: 'figure',
    fade: true,
    speed: 600,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    prevArrow: projectGalleryArrowPrev,
    nextArrow: projectGalleryArrowNext
});

$('.more-projects-gallery').slick({
    speed: 300,
    slide: '.more-projects-gallery__thumbnail',
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    prevArrow: projectGalleryArrowPrev,
    nextArrow: projectGalleryArrowNext,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 800,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3,
                infinite: true
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 680,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2,
                infinite: true
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 410,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                infinite: true
            }
        }
    ]
});
}

/* Initialize slider
=============================== */
$(function(){
    slickSliderConfig();
});
/* Load project content
=============================== */

loadProjectContent = function() {
var $projectContainer = $('.project-container');
var $moreProjectsGalleryImageContainer = $('.more-projects-gallery__thumbnail');
var $moreProjectsGalleryImage = $('.more-projects-gallery__thumbnail img');

// Select specific projects in project-container
var $projectGregMauz = $('#project-gregmauz');
var $projectPersonal = $('#project-personal');
var $projectSyllabus = $('#project-syllabus');
var $projectLemur = $('#project-lemur');

// Select project thumbnails in more-projects-gallery
var $thumbnailGregMauz = $('.more-projects-gallery__thumbnail--gregmauz');
var $thumbnailPersonal = $('.more-projects-gallery__thumbnail--personal');
var $thumbnailSyllabus = $('.more-projects-gallery__thumbnail--syllabus');
var $thumbnailLemur = $('.more-projects-gallery__thumbnail--lemur');

// Hide the non-default specific projects from DOM
$projectPersonal.hide();
$projectSyllabus.hide();
$projectLemur.hide();

// Function for animating scroll
animateScroll = function(element) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
    });
}

// When user clicks Greg Mauz thumbnail image
$thumbnailGregMauz.on("click", function(){
    $projectContainer.children().hide();
    $projectGregMauz.fadeIn(1100).show();
    $('.project-gallery').unslick();
    slickSliderConfig();
    flowTypeConfig();
    animateScroll('#project-gregmauz');
});

// When user clicks Personal thumbnail image
$thumbnailPersonal.on("click", function(){
    $projectContainer.children().hide();
    $projectPersonal.fadeIn(1100).show();
    $('.project-gallery').unslick();
    slickSliderConfig();
    flowTypeConfig();
    animateScroll('#project-personal');
});

// When user clicks Syllabus thumbnail image
$thumbnailSyllabus.on("click", function(){
    $projectContainer.children().hide();
    $projectSyllabus.fadeIn(1100).show();
    $('.project-gallery').unslick();
    slickSliderConfig();
    flowTypeConfig();
    animateScroll('#project-syllabus');
});

// When user clicks Lemur thumbnail image
$thumbnailLemur.on("click", function(){
    $projectContainer.children().hide();
    $projectLemur.fadeIn(1100).show();
    $('.project-gallery').unslick();
    slickSliderConfig();
    flowTypeConfig();
    animateScroll('#project-lemur');
});



}

/* Initialize project content
=============================== */
$(function(){
    loadProjectContent();
});
```

Comment: pics can be picky sometimes

Comment: Am I missing something ... in all the code, I see the reference to the Arrow images that are being dynamically placed.  I assume the main image is also ... but I don't see any reference in code.  I wanted to check the image type; some can cause issues.  In particular, SVG can get really odd but I see you are using them for the arrows.  Is it possible that some option in the SVG is causing the issue?  Can you switch to something more reliable (though larger) like PNG and test?